Why do the numbers of primes counted in uniform small intervals follow a binomial distribution?
Divide the range of integers from 7,998,000,001 to 8,002,000,000 into 40,000 intervals of 100 and count the number of primes in each interval. Combine this data into a distribution d(x) that counts the number of intervals containing x primes. In this case d(x) has non-zero values for x = 0 … 13 , and an average x of 4.385 with a variance of 3.224. The graph of d vs. x looks like a binary distribution, and the average a = Np and variance v = Np(1-p)  infer that the closest match to the data has N = 17 and p = 0.2579. A graph of the data in blue versus the binomial distribution scaled by 40,000 in red shows they are nearly identical:
Since I can't show the graph, the numbers of intervals with 0 to 13 primes were: 254, 1453, 4100, 7140, 8801, 7866, 5567, 3012, 1179, 461, 132, 29, 5, 1
the scaled binary distribution just described has values starting at zero of: 251, 1484, 4125, 7168, 8719, 7878, 5476, 2990, 1299, 451, 126, 28, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, rounded to the nearest integer.
The chi-squared value for data vs distribution is 16.3 indicative of a good fit.
Repeating this for intervals of 200, 400, 800, 1600, and 3200 over ranges giving at least 20,000 cases and centered both at 8 billion and 2 billion shows that in all cases the data is fitted well with a binomial distribution. My Question: Why do the of numbers of primes counted in these uniform intervals have binomial distributions?

binary? binomial?

My mistake. Binomial  not binary.

You should be encouraged by the fact that your calculations are basically following the investigation done by Gauss himself!
The prime number theorem says that the density of primes near a particular number $x$ is approximately $1/\log x$ (the natural logarithm). With $x=8\times 10^9$ as in your examples, we have $1/\log x \approx 0.044$. So the analogous random model would be looking at $100$ samples of a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p\approx 0.044$. In this random model, the mean is about $4.385$ and the variance is about $4.193$.
One can refine this model by using elementary information about the integers, for example that all primes exceeding $2$ must be odd, not multiples of $3$, and so on. (Of course if one does such refinements to their extreme, it's no longer a random model but an actual sieve for primes!) For example, taking into account just divisibility by $2$ and $3$ in this way yields a random model with $33$ or $34$ samples (depending on the particular interval of $100$ numbers) and $p=3/\log x \approx 0.1316$. Note that this is not that different from a random model with half as many samples (approximately $17$) and twice as large a value of $p$ (approximately $0.26$); indeed the original random model isn't that different from a random model with $100/6$ samples and a value $p=6\cdot0.044$.
